# Using more than one geospatial index per collection in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geospatial

[Current MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing/#GeospatialIndexing-CreatingtheIndex) documentation states the following:

> **You may only have 1 geospatial index per collection, for now.** While
>   MongoDB may allow to create multiple indexes, this behavior is
>   unsupported. Because MongoDB can only use one index to support a
>   single query, in most cases, having multiple geo indexes will produce
>   undesirable behavior.

However, when I create two geospatial indices in a collection (using Mongoose), they work just fine:

```
MySchema.index({
  'loc1': '2d',
  extraField1: 1,
  extraField2: 1
});

MySchema.index({
  'loc2': '2d',
  extraField1: 1,
  extraField2: 1
});
```

My question is this: while it seems to work, the MongoDB documentation says this could "produce undesirable behavior". So far, nothing undesirable has not yet been discovered neither in testing or use.

**Should I be concerned about this? If the answer is yes then what would you recommend as a workaround?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is still not supported, so even although you can *create* two of them, it doesn't mean they are actually used properly. I would investigate explain output, on the mongo shell and issue a few queries that make use of the loc and loc2 fields in a geospatial way. For example with:

```
use yourDbName
db.yourCollection.find( { loc: { $nearSphere: [ 0, 0 ] } } ).explain();
```

and:

```
db.yourCollection.find( { loc2: { $nearSphere: [ 0, 0 ] } } ).explain();
```

And then compare what the explain information gives you. You will likely see that only the first created geo index is used for *both* searches. There are a few tickets in JIRA for this that you might want to vote on:

- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2331
- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3653

Comment: Awesome notes, thanks! Going to explore this further. Any ideas on workarounds?

Comment: Either you can use two collections, or you can split up the documents into two parts - where a flag determines whether it was the original "loc" or "loc2" field... no pretty, but it might perhaps work for you.

Comment: Thanks! Also one idea I had is to use an additional list containing both locations as a cache for the geospatial index. But I gotta the say, the most optimal solution would be to be able to use two geospatial indices... Guess I don't have the luxury to do that (yet).